# Conducting change detection analysis on classified land cover classes in ArcGIS Pro

Tags: raster, arcgis-pro, land-cover, change-detection

I have a feature class shapefile consisting of many mangrove polygons and one non-mangrove polygon for my study area. A screenshot of my attribute table shows I have classed mangroves as 1 and non-mangroves as 0. My ultimate goal is to produce 'change' maps between data from 2012, 2017, 2021, and to identify key hotspots of change to be my areas of interest for more in-depth analysis.

I have so far used the feature to raster tool to convert my land cover polygons to raster grids.

I am unsure what the best approaches/tools are to use within ArcGIS Pro for my goals mentioned above. Any advice?

[image: Image 1]

[image: Image 2]

Comment: While you could use rasters to model this, you could also use the vectors (potentially using coarse rasters to identify neighborhoods where more detailed vector modeling would be most appropriate). Unfortunately, we are not an *opinion-based* discussion site. Instead we use a Focused question/Best answer model. In theory, brain-storming questions would be appropriate in [Chat] but there is a minimum reputation requirement to post there (and it doesn't see the traffic of the Q&A site).

Comment: There is a [change detection wizard](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/help/analysis/image-analyst/the-change-detection-wizard.htm) in ArcGIS pro which can be used for this type of change detection.

Comment: Hi @Padmanabha, in the change detection wizard I selected the Categorical Change method, and my before and after rasters. The 'next' button is greyed out and won't allow me to continue

Comment: Hi @Vince, apologies for the format of my question, I will keep that in mind for next time. Using vectors, what would be the appropriate workflow be?